# Thymeleaf layout dialect error TemplateProcessingException: No Standard Expression Parser has been registered as an execution argument

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, dialect

I just learn thymeleaf with spring and encountered a problem. I'm still learning both, and I might miss one or two things in it.

I am templating the page with layout dialect from http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout.

the thymeleaf seems to work fine but it doesn't accept the dialect. And tell me that org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: No Standard Expression Parser has been registered as an execution argument

fyi, This project does not include Spring Boot

full stack here

```
[2016-10-31 03:27:27,702] Artifact eshop-fashion:war exploded: Deploy took 3,259 milliseconds 
2308 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.expressions.ExpressionProcessor - Fragment expression "layouts/layout-main" is being wrapped as a Thymeleaf 3 fragment expression (~{...}) for backwards compatibility purposes.  This wrapping will be dropped in the next major version of the expression processor, so please rewrite as a Thymeleaf 3 fragment expression to future-proof your code.  See https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/451 for more information. 
2319 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-2] Exception processing template "index": An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/templates/index.html]") org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/templates/index.html]”) 
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) 
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:667) 
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1087) at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1061) 
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) 
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) 
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) 
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) 
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) 
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) 
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) 
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) 
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: No Standard Expression Parser has been registered as an execution argument. This is a requirement for using Standard Expressions, and might happen if neither the Standard or the SpringStandard dialects have been added to the Template Engine and none of the specified dialects registers an attribute of type org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.IStandardExpressionParser with name "StandardExpressionParser" (template: "index" - line 2, col 100) 
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) 
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) 
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) 
    ... 37 more 
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: No Standard Expression Parser has been registered as an execution argument. This is a requirement for using Standard Expressions, and might happen if neither the Standard or the SpringStandard dialects have been added to the Template Engine and none of the specified dialects registers an attribute of type org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.IStandardExpressionParser with name "StandardExpressionParser" (template: "index" - line 2, col 100) 
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressions.getExpressionParser(StandardExpressions.java:88) 
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressions$getExpressionParser.call(Unknown Source) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) 
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.expressions.ExpressionProcessor.parse(ExpressionProcessor.groovy:59) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:190) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166) 
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.expressions.ExpressionProcessor.parseFragmentExpression(ExpressionProcessor.groovy:83) 
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.expressions.ExpressionProcessor$parseFragmentExpression.call(Unknown Source) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) 
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.decorators.DecorateProcessor.doProcess(DecorateProcessor.groovy:110) 
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeModelProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeModelProcessor.java:76) 
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementModelProcessor.process(AbstractElementModelProcessor.java:98) 
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementModelProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:649) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1510) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.GatheringModelProcessable.process(GatheringModelProcessable.java:78) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388) 
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169) 
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412) 
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473) 
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201) 
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725) at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) 
    ... 39 more 
 2331 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine
    - [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-4] Exception processing template "index": An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/templates/index.html]") org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/templates/index.html]”) 
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) 
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:667) 
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1087) at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1061) 
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) 
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) 
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) 
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) 
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) 
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) 
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) 
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) 
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: No Standard Expression Parser has been registered as an execution argument. This is a requirement for using Standard Expressions, and might happen if neither the Standard or the SpringStandard dialects have been added to the Template Engine and none of the specified dialects registers an attribute of type org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.IStandardExpressionParser with name "StandardExpressionParser" (template: "index" - line 2, col 100) 
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) 
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) 
    ... 37 more 
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: No Standard Expression Parser has been registered as an execution argument. This is a requirement for using Standard Expressions, and might happen if neither the Standard or the SpringStandard dialects have been added to the Template Engine and none of the specified dialects registers an attribute of type org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.IStandardExpressionParser with name "StandardExpressionParser" (template: "index" - line 2, col 100) 
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressions.getExpressionParser(StandardExpressions.java:88) 
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressions$getExpressionParser.call(Unknown Source) 
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.expressions.ExpressionProcessor.parse(ExpressionProcessor.groovy:59) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:190) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166) 
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.expressions.ExpressionProcessor.parseFragmentExpression(ExpressionProcessor.groovy:83) 
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.expressions.ExpressionProcessor$parseFragmentExpression.call(Unknown Source) 
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.decorators.DecorateProcessor.doProcess(DecorateProcessor.groovy:110) 
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeModelProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeModelProcessor.java:76) 
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementModelProcessor.process(AbstractElementModelProcessor.java:98) 
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementModelProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:649) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1510) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.GatheringModelProcessable.process(GatheringModelProcessable.java:78) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388) 
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169) 
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412) 
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473) 
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201) 
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725) at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) 
    ... 39 more 
 2637 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine
    - [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-6] Exception processing template "index": An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/templates/index.html]") org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/templates/index.html]”) 
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) 
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:667) 
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1087) at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1061) 
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) 
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) 
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) 
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) 
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) 
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) 
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) 
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) 
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: No Standard Expression Parser has been registered as an execution argument. This is a requirement for using Standard Expressions, and might happen if neither the Standard or the SpringStandard dialects have been added to the Template Engine and none of the specified dialects registers an attribute of type org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.IStandardExpressionParser with name "StandardExpressionParser" (template: "index" - line 2, col 100) 
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) 
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) 
    ... 37 more 
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: No Standard Expression Parser has been registered as an execution argument. This is a requirement for using Standard Expressions, and might happen if neither the Standard or the SpringStandard dialects have been added to the Template Engine and none of the specified dialects registers an attribute of type org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.IStandardExpressionParser with name "StandardExpressionParser" (template: "index" - line 2, col 100) 
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressions.getExpressionParser(StandardExpressions.java:88) 
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressions$getExpressionParser.call(Unknown Source) 
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.expressions.ExpressionProcessor.parse(ExpressionProcessor.groovy:59) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:190) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166) 
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.expressions.ExpressionProcessor.parseFragmentExpression(ExpressionProcessor.groovy:83) 
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.expressions.ExpressionProcessor$parseFragmentExpression.call(Unknown Source) 
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.decorators.DecorateProcessor.doProcess(DecorateProcessor.groovy:110) 
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeModelProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeModelProcessor.java:76) 
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementModelProcessor.process(AbstractElementModelProcessor.java:98) 
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementModelProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:649) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1510) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.GatheringModelProcessable.process(GatheringModelProcessable.java:78) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640) 
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388) 
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169) 
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412) 
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473) 
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201) 
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725) 
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) 
    ... 39 more
```

Thymeleaf Configuration

```
private static final String VIEWS = "/WEB-INF/templates/";
@Bean
@Description("Thymeleaf Template Resolver")
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix(VIEWS);
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    return resolver;
}
@Bean
@Description("Thymeleaf Template Engine")
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    templateEngine.setDialect(new LayoutDialect());
    return templateEngine;
}
@Bean
@Description("Thymeleaf View Resolver")
public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver(){
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I do searched and googled a bit and do not found anything that has the same case as mine here. And most of it use spring boot.

How do I fix this??

Answer (score 2):

```
templateEngine.setDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
templateEngine.setDialect(new LayoutDialect());
```

By doing this you replacing StandartDialect (that already presents in template engine) with your LayoutDialect and SecurityDialect. This is not cool.

Not **set** but **add** dialects.

```
templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem, using the following configuration

```
    @Bean
@Primary
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setOrder(2);
    templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("templateEngine")
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
    return templateEngine;
}





@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
    final ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    return viewResolver;
}
```